# build a webpage using php modules

Tags: php, layout, heredoc

I wish to build an HTML page by separating the layout from the content generation. I plan to have say a layout.php page with a matrix structure of div elements (say 3*3). 
For div at location (1,3 - firstrow,third column), I wish to call an advertisement module which will return a travel ad. For div at location(2,3), the same module will be called but this time the HTML for a electronic product will be returned.

The intent here is to separate layout from content generation. So I can change the layout easily. For example, for location (2,3)instead of the static ad, i can call say a weather module that returns HTML showing weather data.

One way I can think of is to have an adv_module.php  which has classes and member functions to return the appropriate ads HTML, with php code as below
i.e.

```
include_once(adv_module.php);adv1 = new ADV_MODULE(); echo adv1->getAd(category=travel)
:
:
include_once(adv_module.php);adv2 = new ADV_MODULE(); echo adv2->getAd(category=electronics
```

)

But then the HTML will have to be constructed within the member functions. This leads to a lot of ugly php code interspersed with the HEREDOC element to help construct the HTML. HEREDOC does not allow conditionals, loops ,etc

Is there a better way to do this? I wish to avoid templating (Smarty like packages) if possible.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid templating? Templating is a *good* thing.

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't PHP itself meant for templating?. Besides templating engines compile to PHP. This may affect performance.

Comment: PHP is a Turing-complete language. Ideal templating languages are not. Using an actual templating engine provides you with a level of abstraction that makes it harder to introduce security issues (e.g. XSS holes) and also helps to enforce the content/logic separation.

Comment: Also regarding performance - any good templating engine will cache its templates and thus usually not have much of a noticeable effect. Worry about performance when it actually becomes an issue; the benefits from using a real templating system are a much more tangible benefit.